# Problem when running Docker image ros:kinetic (standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error")

Tags: linux, docker, ros

I experience some problem when attempt to run my docker image that contains ros kinetic by using :

`docker run --rm -it -e WORKSPACE_NAME=workspace -v $(pwd)/workspace:/root/workspace -w /root/workspace/src ros:mykinetic catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy`

This Is an error: `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"`

The docker file :

```
FROM ros:kinetic

COPY ./ros_entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x ros_entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./ros_entrypoint.sh"]
```

The file entrypoint.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# setup ros environment
source"/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash"

# setup workspace if it exists
if [ -n "$WORKSPACE_NAME" ]; then 
    if [ ! -e "/root/$WORKSPACE_NAME/devel/setup.sh" ]; then
        previousDirectory=$(pwd)
        cd /root/$WORKSPACE_NAME
        catkin_make
        cd $previousDirectory
    fi
    source "/root/$WORKSPACE_NAME/devel/setup.sh"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Output of `docker build --tag ros:mykinetic .` :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  522.8kB
Step 1/3 : FROM ros:kinetic
 ---> 2a18fdb75229
Step 2/3 : COPY ./ros_entrypoint.sh /
 ---> cb9ec00bca0c
Step 3/3 : RUN chmod +x ./ros_entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in 6561ca6d4904
Removing intermediate container 6561ca6d4904
 ---> 11e3b3756027
Successfully built 11e3b3756027
Successfully tagged ros:mykinetic
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by changing the following in the Dockerfile:

> RUN chmod +x ros_entrypoint.sh

for:

> RUN chmod 755 ros_entrypoint.sh